# What's wrong with this lambda expression? "u => ... && u => ..."

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to use logical operators in the following lambda expression

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name");
```

below is the complete function

```
private void Login(int id, string password)
{
    MyDataContext dataContext = new MyDataContext();
    int count = dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name");
}
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express 2008 Edition and User table looks like

```
ID int autogenerated
Name string
```

but Visual Studio 2010 gives the following design time errors "Invalid expression terms". Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

I get the following error messages

- Error 2   ) expected  ...\FormAdd.cs  105 123
- Error 3   ; expected  ...\FormAdd.cs  105 126
- Error 5   ; expected  ...\FormAdd.cs  105 158
- Error 7   ; expected  ...\FormAdd.cs  105 202
- Error 4   Invalid expression term   ')'   ...\FormAdd.cs  105 158
- Error 6   Invalid expression term   ')'   ...\FormAdd.cs  105 202
- Error 1   Invalid expression term   '=>'  ...\FormAdd.cs  105 123

[image: Intellisense doesn't show user object properties]

[image: List of Errors]

Comment: Lambda looks fine to me, are you sure the error is on this line?

Comment: You need to have the expression in a 'where' statement and then call the count() method at the end.

Comment: @Magrangs: No: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx

Comment: Typing `new[] { new { ID=1, Name="name"}}.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name")` into linqpad works for me. Do you have a typo with your ID/Name class?

Comment: @Jason +1 cool didn't actually know that!

Comment: What is the full exception message?

Comment: "Any idea what I might be doing wrong?" Yes, you're not telling us everything. Give us the full message. As written, it looks fine. Therefore, I conclude that you are leaving out a crucial piece of information.

Comment: Yes, the error is on the same line, my code compiles fine if I comment this line.

Comment: Your lambda expression looks good. Provide more code and specs.

Comment: If I use only one predicate, it seems to work fine. When I add another predicate after the logical OR operator it gives error. Seems very odd, but there must be some explanation.

Comment: And it seems to be the case with all functions, Count(), Where(), FirstOrDefault() etc.

Comment: What you've typed in those pictures is not what you've typed in the question. What you've typed in the question is correct. If you want two conditions use `u => u.A == desiredA && u.B == desiredB` not `u => u.A == desiredA && u => u.B == desiredB`.

Comment: @RK: The syntax you show in your screenshot is incorrect. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show in the screenshot is

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u => u.Name == "name");
                                                        **
```

This is illegal code, and the part with the `**` underneath it is the source of the error.

The code you show in the body of your question is

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name");
```

These are different. The first, is incorrect, as the IDE points out to you. The latter, is correct.

The signature for the overload of `Count` you are using is

```
 int Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate);
```

This means to invoke it on `dataContext.Users`, you need to provide a `Predicate<User>`. A `Predicate<User>` is a function that maps `User` to `bool`. One way to write this is

```
 static bool UserPredicate(User u) {
     return u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name";
 }
```

and then you can say

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(UserPredicate);
```

Another way is to say

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(
    delegate(User u) { return u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name" }
);
```

This lets you define the predicate inline. It's a nice feature. Note that the expression that effectively defines the predicate

```
u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name"
```

is the same as in the case of `UserPredicate` defined above.

And finally, Lambda expressions allow you to get rid of some of that unnecessary fluff.

```
int count = dataContext.Users.Count(
    u => f(u)
)
```

Where `f(u)` is an expression in `u`. One expression that you can use is

```
u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "name"
```

Again, the same expression. See, your attempt in the IDE was illegal because you tried to write

```
u.ID == 1 && u => u.Name == "name"
```

and that is clearly not a legal expression.

Comment: Thank you Jason for the detailed explanation. I am new to LINQ and didn't notice this subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to create a similar scenario with the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userList = new List<Users>();
        Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList().ForEach(x => userList.Add(new Users() { ID = x, Name = "Bob" }));

        int count = userList.Count(u => u.ID == 1 && u.Name == "Bob");

        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I am encountering no problems. Are there some specifics in dataContext.Users that could be causing this? Could you provide more information for a repro?

**edit:**

In the screenshots you've attached you have an additional 'u =>' after the && which won't work.

The u => is used at the start to give the body of the expression, which follows the =>, the parameters it uses to operate upon in the body. You're passing the u once at the beginning so you don't need to do it again.

Could you provide similar screenshots/additional information with:

```
int count = this.dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.ID && u.Name == "name");
```

instead, as this should behave correctly?

Comment: Updated the question, please see the details.